# Update data using vuex given items

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have created a module for reservations like this, this is my vuex store:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

const state = {
  reservations: [],
  stats: {
    pending: 0,
    confirmed: 0,
    cancelled: 0  
  } 
};

const actions = {
    
    fetchReservations({commit}){
        axios.get('/reservations').then(({data})=>{
            commit('setReservations', data);      
        }).catch(error => {
            throw new Error(error);
        });
    },
    
    deleteReservation({commit}, reservationId){
        axios.delete('/reservations/'+ reservationId).then(()=>{
            commit('removerReservationInList', reservationId);      
    });
    },

    confirmReservation({commit}, reservationId){        
     axios.patch('/reservations/'+ reservationId +'/confirm').then(({data})=>{                                              
       commit('updateReservationInList', data);  
    });     
    },

    cancelReservation({commit}, reservationId){     
    axios.patch('/reservations/'+ reservationId +'/cancel').then(({data})=>{                                                
      commit('updateReservationInList', data);
    });     
    },

    fetchReservationStats({commit}){    
      axios.get('/reservations/stats').then(({data})=>{                                              
      commit('setReservationsStats', data);              
     });     
    }

};

const mutations = {  

  setReservations(state, reservations) {
    state.reservations = reservations;    
  },

  removeReservationInList(state, reservationId){
        state.reservations = state.reservations.filter((reservation)=>{
            return reservation.id !== reservationId
        });
  },

  updateReservationInList(state, data){
    state.reservations = state.reservations.map(reservation => {        
      if (reservation.id !== data.id) {
        return reservation;
      }     
      reservation.state_id = data.state_id;      
      return reservation;
    });
  },

  setReservationsStats(state, data) {    
    state.stats = data;
  }

};

const getters = {
  reservationsList(state){
    return state.reservations
  },
  reservationsStats(state){
    return state.stats;
  }
};

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state,  
    actions,
    mutations,
    getters
});
```

And those are the reservations:

```
[
    {"id":1,"name":"Rollin Koss","email":"predovic.wyatt@example.net","state_id":2, "booking_date":"2020-12-12","number_of_guests":3},    
    {"id":2,"name":"Kellie Schroeder","email":"nicolette39@example.com","state_id":1,"booking_date":"2020-12-02","number_of_guests":14},    
    {"id":3,"name":"Autumn Goldner IV","email":"vkutch@example.org","state_id":3, "booking_date":"2020-12-15","number_of_guests":14}    
    .....    
]
```

So, I get the stats in other request.
I was thinking doing it in another way, for example, when I get the  reservations, return the stats like this:

```
    [
            "reservations": [
                {"id":1,"name":"Rollin Koss","email":"predovic.wyatt@example.net","state_id":2, "booking_date":"2020-12-12","number_of_guests":3},    
                {"id":2,"name":"Kellie Schroeder","email":"nicolette39@example.com","state_id":1,"booking_date":"2020-12-02","number_of_guests":14},    
                {"id":3,"name":"Autumn Goldner IV","email":"vkutch@example.org","state_id":3, "booking_date":"2020-12-15","number_of_guests":14},
            ....
            ....
            ],
            "stats": {
                "pending": 50,
                "confirmed": 30
                "cancelled": 10      
            }
    ]
```

state_id = 1 is for pending reservations, state_id = 2 is for confirmed reservations, state_id = 3 is for cancelled reservations

And then for example, when I update a pending reservation to confirmed, the pending should decrease and the confirmed should increase, and if a confirmed reservation is cancelled, the stats should reflects that, also, if some reservation is deleted for example a pending, then it should decrease, I am not sure how to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing stats as a state object, you could use a getter which will be reactive to your reservation state.

```
getters: {
stats(state){
  return {
    pending: countState(1),
    confirmed: countState(2),
    cancelled: countState(3),
  };

  function countState(stateId){
    return state.reservations.reduce((acc, cur) => (cur.state_id === stateId ? ++acc : acc), 0);
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** If you'd like it to reflect your current paginated reservations you could move the stats code from vuex into the component itself using a computed function, like so:

```
computed: {
    stats: function () {
        // This should point to your current set of paginated reservations
        const reservations = this.$store.getters.reservations;

        return {
            pending: countState(1),
            confirmed: countState(2),
            cancelled: countState(3),
        };

        function countState(stateId) {
            return reservations.reduce((acc, cur) => (cur.state_id === stateId ? ++acc : acc), 0);
        }
    },
},
```

Comment: That's a good idea, thank you, but what if I use pagination? I mean lets imagine I have 50 pending reservations in total, and I get 10 reservations per page, in that page I get only 4 pending reservations, the stats should reflects all the 50 pending reservations. How could acomplish that?

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I didn't want to reflect current stats per page, I wanted to reflect the pending, cancelled and confirmed reservations in total, so in any page I could modify the reservations even deleted and the total stats should be reflected, how can I do it? thank you.